# Making an excel file into a .CSV doesn't save my edits

Tags: microsoft-excel

I added a picture to explain what I meant by drop boxes since I don't know the actual term for them. After I hide all of the information I don't want shown from the drop box I save the file and make it into a .CSV file, however it never saves those edits in the CSV (Comma delimited) file and shows all of the information checked in the boxes or not.

Answer (score 1):

The drop-boxes are called Autofilters. If you are filtering, then you want to just save the filtered data as a csv, you must either:

a) filter the data as you want it, then copy the filtered data onto a new sheet, then save as CSV from that sheet,

OR

b) filter to show just the data you *don't* want then delete those rows so that the data you want remains, then save as CSV from that sheet